# Pass the frame from the Link layer to the Physical Layer

Tags: c, data-link-layer

I'm trying to create a simple Link layer protocol for school.

I've been searching and googling and I understand that Link layer has pas the frame I create to the Physical layer, but how to do in Programming (language c)
is there a function or library that I can use to send my frame directly using Physical layer ? or how should it be done ?

Answer (score 2):

The most common design patterns to develop communication protocols are the [Protocol Stack Design Pattern](http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/PatternCatalog/protocol_stack.htm#.VHuHG3XOrr4) and the [Protocol Layer Design Pattern](http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/patterncatalog/protocol_layer.htm#.VHuHHXXOrr4). Take a look at it. The links have some example code.

In summary it works as following:

- Communication Upper Layer to Lower Layer: use function parameters
- Communication Lower Layer to Upper Layer: use callback functions

Designing protocols is not trivial and you should keep it simple in the first approaches.

Comment: thanks, it's a bit useful, but it doesn't answer my question. What I'm looking for a how to send packet to the lower layer or how to send packet to another Pc, is there a phyical layer based function or library that I can use to do that ?

Comment: Please specify your question? So you don't want do develop your own protocol? Do you want to use TCP/IP and send a packet using a socket?

Comment: not my own protocol, just the layer. What I'm trying to do is to program the link layer, but in the link layer I have to pass the packet to the lower layer which is the physical layer, but I don't want to program that too. I'm trying to figure out to to pass my packet to the network adapter to do its work or dunno what I should do in order to send the packet to the other PC I'm trying to communicate with.

Comment: I don't think I should use UDP here.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a sockets code ,A socket is one end-point of a two-way communication link between two programs running on the network link. Socket classes are used to represent the connection between a client program and a server program. you do not need to program the physical layer, the OS care with .
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm

Comment: I don't want to use sockets, I want to write my own Link Layer protocol.